# Subprocess.run() gives PermissionError [Errno 13] Permission denied "."

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I have a bash script called min.sh that only prints "launched" as the output. I want to launch it from python (the python script is in the same folder of min.sh).

To do so I'm using `subprocess.run()`, running the command `./min.sh`:

```
a = "./min.sh"
out = subprocess.run([x for x in a.split()], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode("utf-8").split()
```

(I know the split function is useless here, but this instruction is actually made for another task, not just launching bash scripts)

This works and out contains:

```
['launched']
```

Now I want to do the same thing but using a generic bash script through its absolute path (I'm still using the same script, but giving the absolute path). If I was in a terminal the instruction would be

```
. absolutepath/min.sh
```

So I tried with:

```
a = ". absolutepath/min.sh"
out = subprocess.run([x for x in a.split()], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode("utf-8").split()
```

but I got this error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '.'
```

I saw on the internet that I could use `subprocess.call()` instead of `subprocess.run()`, but there is no way to store the output.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: What's the point of using `.` here at all? You don't get any of the advantages of sourcing a program when you run it from a short-lived noninteractive shell such as those `subprocess.Popen`, `os.system`, and equivalents create -- variables it sets don't _stay_ set, working-directory changes don't stick, etc -- so you might as well just run it as a normal subprocess.

Comment: (also, don't name a "bash script" with a .sh extension; see [Commandname Extensions Considered Harmful](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/), which the bash IRC channel has had linked from [its `.sh` factoid](https://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/.sh) for over a decade now -- `.sh` implies something can be run with `sh`, which is a separate shell from bash, and _conventionally_, UNIX executables don't use extensions -- an extension is correct for a shell _library_ you want to source, not a shell _script_ you want to run).

Comment: (...and, again, few of the reasons to create a shell _library_ apply to something you're going to invoke from Python, since the shell you're sourcing the library into will disappear before the `subprocess.call()` or `subprocess.run()` returns)

Comment: I see, thank you. I thought that to run the script I had tu include the dot. Then, now it's even simpler and I think I understood a bit more how it works. Thanks again!

Comment: `./relative/path/to/min.sh` or `/absolute/path/to/min.sh` runs your script as a subprocess assuming you gave it execute permission and a valid shebang (`#!/usr/bin/env bash`) or similar. Again, I'd suggest taking the `.sh` off the name and just calling it `./path/min`

Answer (score 0):

Doing `. path/to/script.sh` will "source" the script into the current shell. Assuming the permissions are correct (executable bit is set and the user running the Python script has execute perms) on min.sh, you can use the absolute path to it without a dot. You can use a dot with the relative path, but don't put a space between the . and the path.

In bash `source` is the same as `.`.

Comment: The important thing this doesn't cover is an explanation of _why_ the OP's current code fails -- that `source` or `.` is a shell builtin, so it can't be run with `execv` (directly replacing the current process with another process without any shell involved), which is what `subprocess.run` and `subprocess.call` invoke when used without `shell=True`. The OP _doesn't have_ any "current shell" at all; the interpreter that runs their code is a Python interpreter, not a shell.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Indeed I put the space because it didn't work without it even on the terminal.

Comment: @chewingram, it _should_ work without the space on the terminal if you have permissions and shebang set up correctly. Check that the file's first line specifies an interpreter (`#!/usr/bin/bash`, `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, or otherwise as appropriate) and that it has executable permissions (`chmod +x /path/to/yourscript`).